# Single threaded Java application - htop shows 14 rows

Tags: java, linux, htop

I have a simple single-threaded application in Java. Surprisingly, when I run it and open htop, I see some 14 child entries, as captured in the following screenshot.

[image: screenshot]

What do these entries represent?

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: Sure it's here on GitHub https://github.com/dusan-rychnovsky/huffman-coder, commit 2a770d0614731fd9a1c6fdcb967f4d769139f03b (currently the latest)

Answer (score 0):

Those are most certainly threads (to confirm, press <kbd>F2</kbd> to enter Setup in htop, select the `Display Options` screen, then check the option `[x] Display threads in a different color`).

Just because you are not creating threads yourself it doesn't that the Java VM doesn't. Check out the following example program:

```
public class Hello {
   public static void main(String S[]) {
      for(;;) {
      }
   }
}
```

It also generates 14 entries in my `htop` window. When I run `jconsole` (a standard tool included with the JDK) and connect to the Hello process, I see the following information:

[image]

The thread names suggest what they do:

- main - my program itself
- Reference Handler
- Finalizer
- Signal Dispatcher
- Attach Listener
- RMI TCP Accept-0
- RMI TCP Connection(1)-127.0.0.1
- RMI Scheduler(0)
- JMX server connection timeout 14
- RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1
- RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1

Some of these like the Finalizer thread are related to the Java garbage collector. Some of these entries above may be related to the fact that the process is connected to `jconsole`, I'm not sure.